# Every Banach space with a Schauder basis also has a nonmonotone basis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

I'm trying to prove that . It's an exercise from Megginson's book, but I'm stuck. I tried to use a summing basis but don't think that works and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What about summing increasing longer sets of basis vectors where you flip signs? Such as $u+v-w$, $u+v+w$, $u-v+w$? Though, it's not clear from that how to estimate their norms.

Comment: Given a basis, $(x_n)$, you need only change the second basis vector $x_2$ in such a way that $\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert$ violates the monotonicity condition.